# How to scan bytecode with sonar scanner

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I was trying to scan a java bytecode by following instructions given in this [link](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Java+Plugin+and+Bytecode)

Looks like sonar scanner looks for property *sonar.source* as it is a mandatory property so it gives error... but in this case i don't have source code as i am doing scanning on binaries files.

So i put the sonar.source property in the property file but didn't mention folder name. In this case i am not getting any report out of it however the scan is running fine through scanner. When i looked into the output of the scanner it shows zero files indexed not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR: if you *only* have the bytecode, then you can't analyze.

The SonarQube platform analyzes and reports on the quality of *source code*. For some languages, such as Java, binaries are also used to get a fuller, more precise analysis. But at root, SonarQube is about source code quality.

That's why `sonar.sources` is a required property: there's no scan without source code. If you're not providing an accurate path to the project's Java source files, then... of course no files are indexed.